# Is there an alternative to accomplishing what the FileSystemWatcher does in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, filesystemwatcher

I have an OOB Silverlight 4 application (I can upgrade to Silverlight 5 if it makes this easier to accomplish), and I need to monitor a file in the My Documents folder for changes.

The file is modified by another program running on the machine, when the file changes, I need my silverlight application to react to the changes.

It appears that the FileSystemWatcher is not available in silverlight, so right now I see my only solution is some kind of polling where I just check the file on some sort of short timer.

This seems like this could be a somewhat big performance hit.

Is there a common way of doing this that I'm not aware of?  Is there anyway to get the FileSystemWatcher working in silverlight?

Comment: Why don't you convert your application to wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to PInvoke the API: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindFirstChangeNotification.html

See also an MSDN example of using this API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa365261

This will require the use of Silverlight 5, Out of Browser and elevated permissions and a Windows OS.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Yes, I forgot to mention that. Thank you!