# Accessing local file system on browser

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Please hear me out before you start crying security issues.

This is for an intranet application, hence I have full range to install any plugins or change any security permissions to suit.

What I want is for them to go to a webpage and click a link to download a file, such as a Word Document. This gets transferred to local storage of some kind (sandboxed if need be) and then is opened in word as a regular file.

When they click save, JavaScript or something will pickup the file is saved or the program is no longer accessing it and can be actioned upon, such as uploading back up to the server.

Is there any way to do this. I have looked at IndexedDb, WebStorage, HTML5 FileSystem API but I am new to all and don't see a way to do this.

I am open to coding any needed plugins as long as you don't mention Flash. The main issue I am coming across is opening a file downloaded into some form of local browser and then opening it via a desktop application, e.g. Word.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do this in a few lines of PHP. I wouldn't bother to use JS; you're on an intranet you can literally use anything. A server side language is far more suited for that, you can run bash scripts, open files, no limitations or workarounds.

Comment: I was wanting to do this on the client machine, not server side.

Comment: I don't think you can interact with Word from the browser. The best you can do is give the file the proper extension and hope that the user's browser opens the file in Word. Maybe with something like ActiveX or Flash but not with web technologies AFAIK.

Comment: I don't need it to interact with Word, a simple file watcher would do the trick in this instance. Just watching when all access to it releases or when the file is updated. The trick being able to have Word or any other program access the local file as they are normally sandboxed to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research the only way to do it is with a plugin. IndexedDB, FileSystem API or WebStorage can not access the local file system. Which is good.

Silverlight is a good option for intranet and .NET, which is what I have chosen to go with.

Silverlight 5 in full permissions with a file watcher. The file watcher can be accomplished with this method: [Is there an alternative to accomplishing what the FileSystemWatcher does in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886543/is-there-an-alternative-to-accomplishing-what-the-filesystemwatcher-does-in-silv)

Comment: In browsers that support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), it is possible to modify files without using a plugin.