# Save img tag in local disk in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to store image of base64 type.

Save to local drive.

For example save in `c:\temp\image.png`

```
// Image type base64
var images = $('.cropme img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the image source to base64 string as follows-->

```
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' );
```

Here you go,on right click on this image you can save it to your local drive easily. :)

If you want to download it onclick of button you have to use html5 download attribute as show here http://jsfiddle.net/3EjUg/5/

Comment: hi my dear. no right click on this image. click button and save it to my local drive.

Comment: You can also directly assign the image src and a href to base64 string :)

Comment: i want create function with 2 input arguments. (string path, string src).
save image in path. for example:
Function("c:\temp\image\", "data:image/png;base64,iVBO...")

Comment: You cant access the local path directly using pure js.

Comment: Javascript can't access the users drive. That would be a big security issue, wouldn't it? :D

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

```
var save = document.createElement('a');
save.href = $('#myImageID').attr('src');
save.target = '_blank';
save.download = 'photo.jpg'

var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('click', true, true);
save.dispatchEvent(event);
(window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
```

You need to trigger this code from a user gesture (e.g. click on a button).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script>
 var imagedata="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/..";
 document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src',imagedata);
 document.getElementById('anchor').setAttribute( 'href',imagedata);
</script>
```

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xemo8xzk/2/)

Comment: save to path! for example: save in c:\temp\image\img1.png

Comment: Accessing local file system on browser is not possible refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16391710/3464552